# Returning null instead of "Call to undefined relationship" error for Laravel relationships

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

When I use `ModelName::with('somerelation')->get()` with Laravel Eloquent, if the model doesn't have this relationship I get `Call to undefined relationship [somerelation] on model [App\SomeModel]` error.

But for polymorphic relations, I get collection of all related models and I would like to use `with('somerelation')` and get `null` if relationship is not defined. Is there any way to avoid error and return null from with() or any way to use with conditionally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I do on all my Laravel projects is creating a Model class that extends Eloquent Model and all my models will extend my Model class, so I can override some methods from Eloquent Model using my rules.

So you can create a new class (I call it Model) and override the method with with a try/catch block retuning null in the case this exception is thrown by eloquent model.

Example:

```php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as EloquentModel;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\RelationNotFoundException;

abstract class Model extends EloquentModel
{
    public static function with($relations)
    {
        try {
            return parent::with($relations);
        } catch (RelationNotFoundException $e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Previous answer by @Leonardo Oberle doesn't work for me.
I was struggling by finding a way how to validate the integrity of a relationship string passed to the `with()` method, so it will load relation only upon it exists, and will not throw errors if something is missing.

So, I ended up creating a abstract Model class which extends from EloquentModel and overwrites the `with()` method as in `Leonardo Oberle's` response.

The only thing is that the method's code should look like :

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as EloquentModel;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\RelationNotFoundException;

abstract class Model extends EloquentModel
{
    public static function with($relations)
    {
        $filteredRelations = $this->relationExistsUntil($relations);

        parent::with($filteredRelations);

    }
}


    /**
     * @param string $with
     * @return string
     */
    protected function relationExistsUntil(string $with): string
    {
        $model = $this;
        $result = '';
        $relationParts = explode('.', $with);

        foreach ($relationParts as $relationPart) {
            $isValidRelation = method_exists($model, $relationPart) && $model->{$relationPart}() instanceof Relation;

            if (!$isValidRelation) {
                break;
            }

            $result .= empty($result) ? $relationPart : ".$relationPart";
            $model = ($model->{$relationPart}()->getRelated());
        }

        return $result;
    }



So, with that, if you will try smth like


`$user->with('relation1.relation2.relation3');`
where `relation2` doesn't exist, it will load only `relation1` and the rest will be skipped, and no exceptions/errors would be thrown.

Just don't forget to make all models then extend from that new abstract class.
```